# How to set DOCUMENT_ROOT in PHP

Tags: php

[image: console]
Hello everyone!

I know this question may seem a bit odd, but it seems to be impossible for me to set the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` path for PHP.

I've tried anything, but nothing works.

When I type in CMD (I'm on Windows 10) "php -t C:\Users\infinitecodes\www" it just doesn't work, the CMD just hangs and it doesn't "complete" the command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find your PHP installation directory and copy it's path.

> It should be like this "C:\wamp\bin\php{your php folder is here\"

2. Go to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System".
3. Click “Environment Variables…” (bottom screen).
4. Search for Path.
   [image]
5. Click “New”.
6. Paste the PHP path from the first step.
7. Click OK 3 times and close “system window”.

Comment: Already done that, i found now where i have to put in the doc_root but i still have an issue. Whether i type in the (absolute) path for the doc_root it doesnt work. I tried to type it with the "" and without the quotation marks. I dont know what to do.

Comment: It should be like this "C:\wamp\bin\php{your php folder is here\", in my case its "C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.0\"